# Check if element from List is available in Data Frame columns and create a new column to add value if condition is True

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a below data frame and two lists. I want to check if the item from `list1` is available in `Description` column then create a new column and add a label '`weather`'. Similarly for `list2` , I need to add label '`equipment`'.

```
list1 = ['wind','air']
list2 = ['crane','machine']

df

Description
There was a heavy wind due to cyclone.
Pollution hamper the air quality.
The machine failure was due to short circuit.
The game was called off due to wind.
Players played the game very well.
the crane operator took the crane to wrong side
```

expected output

```
Description                                            Label
There was a heavy wind due to cyclone.                 weather
Pollution hamper the air quality.                      weather
The machine failure was due to short circuit.          equipment
The game was called off due to wind.                   weather
Players played the game very well.                     Other
the crane operator took the crane to wrong side.       equipment
```

I tried the below code, but in the final data it gives me label as 'Other' for all the descriptions.

```
df['Description'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('|'.join(list1)),'weather','Other')
df['Description'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains('|'.join(list2)),'equipment','Other')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and easy fix of your code is to use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['Label'] = np.select([df['Description'].str.contains('|'.join(list1)),
                         df['Description'].str.contains('|'.join(list2))],
                        ['weather', 'equipment'], 'Other')
```

However, you can do better.

You can use an automatically crafted regex and a mapping dictionary:

```
import re

d = {'weather': ['wind','air'], 'equipment': ['crane','machine']}

# reverse d
d2 = {k: v for v,l in d.items() for k in l}
# {'wind': 'weather', 'air': 'weather',
#  'crane': 'equipment', 'machine': 'equipment'}

pattern = f"({'|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(d2, key=len, reverse=True)))})"
# '(machine|crane|wind|air)'

df['Label'] = (df['Description'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
               .map(d2).fillna('Other')
               )
```

And if you can have more than one match per sentence:

```
df['Label'] = (df['Description'].str.extractall(pattern)[0]
               .groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.drop_duplicates()))
              )
```

Output:

```
                                       Description      Label
0           There was a heavy wind due to cyclone.    weather
1                Pollution hamper the air quality.    weather
2    The machine failure was due to short circuit.  equipment
3             The game was called off due to wind.    weather
4               Players played the game very well.      Other
5  the crane operator took the crane to wrong side  equipment
```

Comment: I used your first solution, however I want to know if I have to check if all the element in list1 is available then only i label them or else put them as "other", then what changes I have to do?

Comment: @Adityasharma it's not fully clear, can you maybe open a new question with the appropriate examples?

Comment: I have open a new question for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76617607/check-if-all-the-element-from-list-is-available-in-data-frame-column-and-create

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work like this:

```
df["Label"] = "Other"
df["Label"][df["Description"].str.contains('|'.join(list1))] = "weather"
df["Label"][df["Description"].str.contains('|'.join(list2))] = "equipment"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with `.apply()` where you can get a little more control over the logic being used fill the `label` column:

```
df['label'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: 'weather' if any(word in x for word in list1) else ('equipment' if any(word in x for word in list2) else 'other'))
```