# Check if all the element from List is available in Data Frame column and create a new column to add value if condition is True

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a below data frame and two lists. I want to check if `all` the item from `list1` is available in Description column then create a new column and add a label '`weather`'. Similarly for `list2` , I need to add label '`equipment`'.

```
list1 = ['wind','air']
list2 = ['crane','failure']

df

Description
There was a heavy wind and air dust due to cyclone.
Pollution hamper the air quality.
The machine failure was due to short circuit.
The game was called off due to wind.
Players played the game very well.
the crane operator took the crane to wrong side.This leads to failure operation.
```

expected output

```
Description                                            Label
There was a heavy wind and air dust due to cyclone.    weather
Pollution hamper the air quality.                      Other
The machine failure was due to short circuit.          Other
The game was called off due to wind.                   Other
Players played the game very well.                     Other
the crane operator took the crane to wrong side.This   equipment
leads to failure operation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper function to return the label, and then pass it into the pandas apply function:

```
def return_label(text):
    if all(word in text for word in ['wind','air']):
        return "weather"
    if all(word in text for word in ['crane','failure']):
        return "equipment"
    return "Other"

df['Label'] = df.Description.apply(lambda x: return_label(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logic similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76515832/16343464), then map from a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) of the items:

```
import re

# define here the combinations of words and the matching Label
combinations = {frozenset(['wind', 'air']): 'weather',
                frozenset(['crane', 'failure']): 'equipment',
              # frozenset(list_of_terms): 'label',
              # as many as you want
               }

pattern = f"({'|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(set().union(*combinations), key=len, reverse=True)))})"
# (failure|crane|wind|air)'

df['Label'] = (df['Description']
               .str.extractall(pattern)[0]
               .groupby(level=0).agg(frozenset)
               .map(combinations).reindex(df.index).fillna('Other')
              )

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                         Description      Label
0  There was a heavy wind and air dust due to cyc...    weather
1                  Pollution hamper the air quality.      Other
2      The machine failure was due to short circuit.      Other
3               The game was called off due to wind.      Other
4                 Players played the game very well.      Other
5  the crane operator took the crane to wrong sid...  equipment
```

Comment: I just want to add here that I have 8 List of combination .What should I do in that case. I have used your other method.

Comment: Just update the initial dictionary `d` with more combinations. Actually, let me simplify the format a bit to have a single dictionary `combinations`.